# codeigniter issue with ajax post

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, post

I'm trying with Ajax call 3 arguments to controller but its gave me error `Missing argument 1 and 2 and 3`, I know that Codeigniter just accept 1 argument so I tried to add inside the function:

```
$calibracao_data = $this->uri->segment(3);
$user_a_drop = $this->uri->segment(4);
$status = $this->uri->segment(5);
```

but nothing worked, also I echo inside the function the variables and didn't get success.
changed the config file: `$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:&_\-';` and nothing

the code of ajax:

```
<script>
function get_active(calibracao_data, user_a_drop, ativo){
    var fieldcal = $("input#calibracao_data").val();
    var field1 = fieldcal.replace("/", "-");
    var field2 = $("select#user_a_drop").val();
    var field3 = ativo;
    jQuery.ajax({

    url: "<?php echo base_url().'instrumentos/get_proximocal_cliente_status/'; ?>",
    data: { field1: field1, field2: field2, get_status: field3 },
    success: function(g) { 
        //alert (g); 
        $(".post_table").html(g);
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         alert("some error");
    }
});
};
```

and the return from console is:

```
http://localhost/apoio/app/instrumentos/get_proximocal_cliente_status/?field1=04-16&field2=75&get_status=Ativo
```

please help.

Comment: You aren't creating uri segments in ajax.... you are creating query string which is different.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
$calibracao_data = $this->input->get('field1');
$user_a_drop = $this->input->get('field2');
$status = $this->input->get('field3');
```

Or add `method: "POST",` property to AJAX object.

Don't change anything in config file such is permitted chars parameter if you can't realize all consequences.

Comment: also note to remove arguments from controller method

Answer (score 0):

```
  var param = {
   fieldcal : $("input#calibracao_data").val(),
   field1 : fieldcal.replace("/", "-"),
  field2 : $("select#user_a_drop").val(),
   field3 :ativo
}
    $.ajax({

    type: "POST",

    url: "<?=base_url()?>.'instrumentos/get_proximocal_cliente_status",

    data: param,

    cache: false,

    success: function(rs)

    {

    $(".post_table").html(rs);
    },

    }

    });
```

hi check above code its work for me